# Biblatex: Sorting by Alphabet in Bibliography problems with authorname prefixes

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

I have a bibliography with a bunch of legal documents, for which I use the misc type. I use sorting nyt. However, it does not recognise the Author "De-Minimis-Verordnung" as starting with a "d", but rather starting with an "m", which is faulty. I think biblatex thinks this "de-" is some sort of prefix. How do I turn this behavior off?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autocite=footnote, maxcitenames=3, language=german, style=authoryear-ibid, backend=biber, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\bibliography{lit.bib}

\begin{document}

Test\autocites{eukom15122009}[]{deminimisvo}[]{mitteilungsdai}

\printbibliography[title={Gesetzesmaterialien der Europ\"aischen Union}, type=misc]

\end{document}
```

With the following lit.bib file

```
@misc{eukom15122009,
    Author = {{European Commission}},
    Howpublished = {State aid},
    Year = {2009}}

@misc{deminimisvo,
    Author = {{De-minimis-Verordnung}},
    Howpublished = {Verordnung (EU) Nr. 1407/2013},
    Year = {2013}}

@misc{mitteilungsdai,
    Author = {{Mitteilung der Kommission}},
    Year = {2013}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the default `\DeclareNosort` setting which strips two letters followed by a dash from strings before sorting. You can fix this by putting this in your preamble:

```
\DeclareNosort{
  \nosort{type_name}{\regexp{}}
}
```

Comment: To avoid this mixing up f.e. regular author names of the book and article type, do you have a suggestion on how to limit this command to "misc"-type documents?

Comment: The right way to do this is to define a custom name field for entities that are not people and you can then define different nosort options for the different fields.